# How to use Threading.Thread.Sleep with string values

Tags: vba

I typed: Threading.Thread.Sleep(aarray(1))

There are no errors at first but then when the program runs and the user defines the time to wait. The aarray thing is a string, but why would it freeze up even if it is a string, why not just type some numbers into it?
If you have an answer, then please say a code that would work with a string.

Comment: You can't use Thread.Sleep with string values, this request makes no sense. What did you expect would happen? Also, what is in that string? Did you expect a string like `"1000"` to be handled the same way as `Thread.Sleep(1000)`? It is very hard to provide any sort of answer since I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Looks like vb.Net not vba to me